# How to use YML files for a Mojito project?

Tags: yaml, mojito

It is said that Mojito can use JSON or YML as the `application.json` (the config file), but I haven't seen YML examples around?

For example, how to convert:

```
[
    {
        "settings": [ "master" ],
        "specs": {
            "hello" : {
                "type" : "HelloWorldMojit"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

to a YML file?

Also, when we use

```
$ mojito create app Hello
```

can't we specify that we want YML files as the default (instead of JSON files)?

---

Details:

I used npm's yamljs to convert the file to:

```
-
  settings: [master]
  specs: { hello: { type: HelloWorldMojit } }
```

and it doesn't work.  And I edited it to

```
-
  settings: [master]
  specs:
      hello:
          type:
              HelloWorldMojit
```

It won't work either.  The server can start, but when the homepage was accessed, the error is:

```
error: (outputhandler.server): { [Error: Cannot expand instance [hello], 
       or instance.controller is undefined] code: 500 }
```

(the file `routes.json` is depending on `hello` being defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Mojito 0.5.2, YML is supported again.  0.5.1 and 0.5.0 do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have `archetypes` with `yaml`, you will have to transform the files manually and renaming them. The good news, a more flexible `archetypes` infrastructure is on the making.

You should be ok with that configuration you pasted in the question, just use the latest version of mojito (0.5.x)

Comment: j0k isn't actually the one who posted the question; he just edited it. 動靜能量 is the one who posted the question.